# How to set time depends form other input in (Datetimepicker Jquery plugin)?

Tags: jquery

Could you help me?
I would like in first input set only start date with time:

```
$("#startdate")
```

In second one:

```
$('#enddate')
```

should be already selected choosen  day ,but time cannot be earlier than choosen but also not greater than midnight.
 For example:
 In first text box I choose 1 January 2017  15:00
In second test box I can choose only 1 January 2017 and time between 15:00-23:59. I tried something with minTime and maxTime This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#startdate").datetimepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd   HH:i",
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    minTime:'10:00',
    startDate : new Date('2017-01-01'),
    endDate : new Date('2017-01-15'),
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    var maxDate = new Date(minDate);
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('setDate', maxDate);
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('datepicker', false);
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('format', 'H:i');
});
  $("#enddate").datetimepicker();
 });
```

Here's fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/zqxhqaf8/38/

Answer (score 0):

Try with setHours method

```
var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
var maxDate = new Date(minDate.setHours(23,59,59,999));
```